# RichEdit get line from pixel position

Tags: c++builder, vcl, trichedit, c++builder-xe5

If I click inside a TRichEdit control, how can I get the Line index (I clicked on) from the mouse client coordinates?

In other words, how do I convert a client coordinate to a Line Index?

***EDIT
I'm actually not clicking inside the TRichEdit control, I'm clicking in another control and need to synch with the TRichEdit control's line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send [`EM_CHARFROMPOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`EM_LINEFROMCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages to the RichEdit, eg:

```
POINTL pt = ...; // client coordinates
int pos = RichEdit1->Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, (LPARAM)&pt);
int idx = RichEdit1->Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, pos, 0);
```